# Netlogo use of myself

Tags: netlogo

With the use of the `myself` primitive, I want a patch with a certain land use to make buildings of that type in a specific radius, but it's not working. Here is the code:

```
patches-own [land-use] ;land-use can take many types: "residential", "industrial", "commercial"

...

to grow
ask patches with [land-use = "residential"] 
  [ask other patches in-radius 10 [
    if [land-use = "residential"] of myself [build-house]]]
end
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

The problem there is not `myself` but the use of `of`. Two things to fix:

1. `of` requires the reporter to be in square brackets. Only the reporter that `of` refers to, not the whole condition being tested (as in your case where you are testing a condition).
2. You should not specify the value of the variable but just its name. Just as in normal language: you wouldn't say "If your hair colour equals my blonde", but you would say "If your hair colour equals my hair colour".

The resulting syntax is:

```
if (land-use = [land-use] of myself) [
  build-house
]
```

Parentheses surrounding the condition are optional, I use them as a stylistic choice.

---

**PS** Regarding point 2 above... of course you could keep the value of the variable (i.e. `"residential"`) instead of the name of the variable (i.e. `land-use`), and in that case drop `of myself`.

You would have:

```
if (land-use = "residential") [
  build-house
]
```

And as of now it would work because the patches starting this process are just those with `land-use = "residential"`... but this doesn't look like great code, as it is not extendable to other variable's values and it contains more hard-coding than necessary.